# Debugging Unicorn server remotely with RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, unicorn, ruby-debug-ide

I have *Rails* (version 4.0.3) application which uses *nginx* as front-end server to dispatch the requests to actual *Unicorn*. Whilst developing the app I would like to use *Docker* on Windows (boot2docker) to run the application and [*ruby-debug-ide*](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide) to debug the application remotely.

The original setup works fine (application answers on the host machine) until I replace `rails server` with

```
rdebug-ide --port 1234 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 26162 -- bin/rails server
```

After running this on the Docker container I connect to the remote debugger successfully as it tells on Docker containers bash that breakpoints were added based on what I've set on RubyMine and tells that Unicorn server is now running. I added gem [*unicorn-rails*](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/unicorn-rails) to make `rails server` work for Unicorn too.

Now the actual problem is that the nginx can't seem to find the Unicorn when it as ran within the debugger. It just keeps on loading on browser (and with curl) until 504 (gateway timeout) is returned.

The interesting Unicorn configuration contains

```
app_dir = "/app"
working_directory app_dir
pid "#{app_dir}/tmp/unicorn.pid"
worker_processes 1
listen "/tmp/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
```

I have set up everything as described on [JetBrains help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/remote-debugging.html). On Docker I have all the necessary ports (1234 for debugger, 26162 for dispatcher, 443 for HTTPS) open.

I've crawled Internet and Stack Overflow for hours without any luck and can't find anything to try anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Listing the `docker` commands you used might help.

Comment: Taking into account the fact that the those ports are open that I declared, I thought, there was no use for that. But it is just plain `docker run -d -p 443:443 -p 1234:1234 -p 26126:26126 --net=bridge <my-image>`

Comment: Did you resolve that issue? Could you provide more detailed info have to use docker with Rubymine? Is you docker image published somewhere publicly?

Comment: Nope, didn't get it resolved, just gave up with that. Maybe I'll give it a shot in the future.